# javaFX 2.2 - Not able to populate table from Controller

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have below code. when i try to run, table does not display record on GUI. Can you please suggest?

fxml_tableview.fxml - fxml which describe table structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.collections.*?> 
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import fxmltableview.*?> 

<Scene width="400" height="550" fx:controller="fxmltableview.FXMLTableViewController" 
       xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

    <GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
        <TableView fx:id="tableView" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="tradeId" text="Trade ID" prefWidth="200"/>
            </columns>    
        </TableView>
    </GridPane>
</Scene>
```

FXMLTableViewController.java //controller where I am trying to populate table columns.

```
 package fxmltableview;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;

    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

    public class FXMLTableViewController implements Initializable{
        @FXML private TableView<Trade> tableView;
        ObservableList<Trade> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Trade("1"));

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        tableView.setItems (data);
    }
}
```

FXMLTableView.java //Java main class

```
   package fxmltableview;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class FXMLTableView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("FXML TableView Example");
        primaryStage.setScene((Scene)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_tableview.fxml")));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Trade.java //Data model for table

```
   package fxmltableview;

    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

    public class Trade {

    private SimpleStringProperty tradeId = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public Trade(String tradeId) {
        setTradeId(tradeId);
    }

    public String getTradeId() {
        return tradeId.get();
    }

    public void setTradeId(String a) {
        tradeId.set(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick guess is that you forgot to set the cell value factory of the tablecolumn.

```
@FXML private TableColumn<Trade, String> tradeId;
```

then in init:

```
tradeId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Trade, String>("tradeId"));
```

Comment: can u help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463931/javafx-tableview-is-empty?