# JavaFX Tableview data doesn't show

Tags: java, mysql, uitableview, javafx, scenebuilder

I've made a controller which is supposed to get data from MySQL database and display it in a tableview made with Scene Builder. I'm new to Java so I might've written the code in a weird way, but I've gotten everything to work except that the data doesn't show although it makes a new row:

Snip of the tableview

[image: Snip of the tableview]

I don't get any errors and can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. The code is:

```
//package and imports are here... 

public class PatientOverviewController {

    @FXML
    private Label lblMessage;
    @FXML
    private TextField patientSearchField;
    @FXML
    private TableView<InvoiceEntry> patientTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<InvoiceEntry,Double> CPRColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<InvoiceEntry,String> nameColumn;

    private ObservableList data;

    public class InvoiceEntry {

        public SimpleStringProperty patName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public SimpleDoubleProperty patCPR = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        public String getPatName() {
            return patName.get();
        }

        public void setPatName(String dbName){
            patName.set(dbName);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty patNameProperty(){
            return patName;
        }

        public Double getPatCPR() {
            return patCPR.get();
        }

        public void setPatCPR(Double dbCPR) {
            patCPR.set(dbCPR);            
        }

        public SimpleDoubleProperty patCPRProperty() {
            return patCPR;
        }
    }

     /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     *
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @FXML
    @SuppressWarnings("Convert2Diamond") //I don't understand why this has to be here
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry,String>("patName"));
        CPRColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry,Double>("patCPR"));
    }

    @FXML
    private void btnSearchAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); // create the data
        patientTable.setItems(data); // assign the data to the table

        DBConnection dbConn = new DBConnection();
        Connection conn = dbConn.connect();

        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        try {
            String SQL = "SELECT `CPR`,`firstName`,`lastName` FROM `Patient` WHERE `CPR` = ?;"; 

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            pstmt.setString(1, patientSearchField.getText()); 
            ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery();

            while (result.next()) {
                String dbName = result.getString("firstName") + " " + result.getString("lastName");
                Double dbCPR = result.getDouble("CPR"); 

                InvoiceEntry entry = new InvoiceEntry();
                entry.patCPR.set(dbCPR);
                entry.patName.set(dbName);
                data.add(entry);

                System.out.println(dbName);
            }    
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error" + e);
        } finally {
            pstmt.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to view this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868489/unable-to-insert-values-into-tableview-javafx

Comment: Is `System.out.println(dbName);` printing the new rows in the console?

Comment: @Aubin Yes it is, but I've figured it out thanks to Zaknafein

I was missing the  <cellValueFactory> and <PropertyValueFactory> tags under the <TableColumn> tag for each columns in the FXML file :-)

Comment: @Zaknafein Thank you!!